# What does "private static final" mean in Java?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android and I'm just scratching surface of it. When I was going through some Tutorials I came across this class to Download the File. I was able to understand Other code but I am unableto understand what does

```
  private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
```

Does? Is this really necessary? what if It is not declared First.

Below is the Code

```html
public class FileDownloader {
    private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It must be very stupid Question but I was really curious to know How and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Means the same in Android as in any other Java environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `private static final` declaration means that that value is **declared as a constant**. There is nothing special with it, it is just a good coding practice to place the hard-coded values as constants. It is for the sake of code readability and maintainability.

Your code is basically creating a **buffer of 1 MB** for downloading files.

That means when downloading a file, first 1 MB is downloaded into your RAM, then that part is copied to file output stream (Disk), and this process will repeat until everything is downloaded. Note that if everything was downloaded to RAM, your device may run out of memory and app would throw `OutOfMemoryError`. Also note that you can choose any value instead of 1 MB for your buffer.

Comment: This one is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

`MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024` mean number of bytes in a `MB` known as megabyte

```
8 bits      = 1 byte
1024 bytes  = 1 kb 
1024 kb     = 1 Mb
```

and 1 Mb contains `1048576`. bytes which is equal to `1024 * 1024`

`inputStream.read` will try to read this amount bytes from the steam and put it inside the byte array

```
 data_read_as_byte      return
     > 0                number of bytes read
     < 0                  -1

 // return 0 when passed array size is 0
```

Comment: What if it was mentioned private static final int  MEGABYTE = 2048 * 2048; instead, will it give me error?

Comment: nope, `private : use within this class`, `static : can use used FileDownloader.MEGABYTE ` and `final : value cannot be changed`

Comment: I was saying instead of private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024; what if I declared and replaced with private static final int MEGABYTE = 2048 * 2048; will it give me any error or what ma I doing wrong here? sorry for my bad english/

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: The only "error", if you could call it that, would be that the name `MEGABYTE` would now be inaccurate, because the value would be **four** megabytes rather than [one] megabyte!

Answer (score 1):

> > ```
> > private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
> > ```
> >
> > Does ?

Declared a variable that is `final`, `private` and `static`

What it is necessarily doing is that you can reference `MEGABYTE` variable inside any method of `FileDownloader` class(`because it is private`), be it `static` or `not`.

If it would have `declared inside any method`, then it's `scope` would be within that method only.

If it would have been `declared without static` keyword, then it would not be accessible in `static` method. You can try it yourself by removing the `static` keyword.

> > Is this really necessary? what if It is not declared First.

In the given class, there is only one `static method` and this variable is declared as `private`, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to declare it in such a way. Declaring this variable inside your method should also be fine

Instantiating `MEGABYTES` less than `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` should be fine